# Get start date the calendar week

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using google spreadsheet and have the calendar week and the date.

I want to get for each calendar week the start date of the week.

Find below an example:

[image]

Find here my google sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k-KTzyeVo7tNQOBm42bq0JroF_SugTaLvEGsr5Gt-CA/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggestions how to get the start date of the week?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anna, I have set up a new sheet called "Erik Help" and placed the following array formula into cell E5:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:2="","",DATE($E$2,1,1)+((E3:3-1)*7)-(WEEKDAY(DATE($E$2,1,1),2)-1)))
```

Since this is an array formula, it "runs" the entire row. No need to drag across.